# Postman body encryption

Tags: postman

I wonder if there is a way to intercept requests and responses and modify the body.

My problem is that I am using an API with requests and responses body encrypted and I would like to build requests with non encrypted data and be able to see responses' body decrypted also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to do this. You can easily intercept a request and modify any part of it, before the response is sent back.